# Ignore not declared variables (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am creating a WebExtension using TypeScript which is later compiled to JavaScript.

My extension depends on one of the APIs the browser (Firefox) offers, specifically the [extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/extension) API. As an example, I use the getURL() method, which is called like this:

```
browser.extension.getURL("foo/bar.js");
```

Of course, TypeScript gives an error "Cannot find name 'browser'". This prevents me from fully compiling the code. I would like to know if there is any way to bypass this. Preferably not only at compile level, but also at the linting level.

I have tried:

- Defining `browser` at the beginning as `var browser: any;`:  breaks the API.
- Compiling with `--noEmit`, `--noEmitOnErrors`: irrelevant, still complains.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can also try 

      browser['extension']['getURL']("foo/bar.js");

Comment: @mpm Apparently a `var` between `declare` and `browser` is needed, as  @TitianCernicova-Dragomir said. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to let Typescript know that the variable exists but not actually emit any code for it you can use `declare`

```
declare var browser: any;
```

Comment: Better to use a `.d.ts` file?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you could use one but for just one variable of type any I would not bother.

Comment: I was tearing my hair out on a way to refer to a variable that was injected into the rendering template server-side but couldn't figure out a way to do it. This did the trick!